# Chart.js: how to stretch line on x-axis?

Tags: chart.js

We have multiple data to be shown in one chart. Each of them has 60 values, one for every minute per hour. But one of them has just 30 (data for every even minute only). When I add them to my chart, this one shows only to half of the chart canvas, although it is supposed to be shown over the full width of chart. I have tried several options, but no luck. How to "stretch" this line?

Image: the red line has 30 values, all others have 60. How can I stretch the red line to full width?

[image]

minimal example code:

```
var chartData = {
    labels: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Battery",
            data: [10,30,20,10,40,50,70,100,30,20],
            borderColor: "blue",
        },
        {
            label: "Speed",
            data: [30,20,10,40,50],
            borderColor: "red",
        },
    ]
};

// Define the chart options
var chartOptions = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    legend:{
        display: true
    } 
};

// Create the chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: chartData,
    options: chartOptions,
});
```

Comment: Without code it's hard to tell -- there are several ways to represent data to produce that chart. As a very generic advice, you may try adding a `null` between each two consecutive values and set `options.spanGaps = 60000` (1min)

Comment: have added minimal example code, please advise

Comment: Right, now we can go forward!  [This](https://jsfiddle.net/zcm6wpa8/) is a possible solution based on adding `null`s. [This one](https://jsfiddle.net/hkvtpcm7/) does a more thorough mapping of data. A more precise solution would have to take into consideration what type of axis is your (production) x-axis: linear, time, or category. Please let me know what you think

Comment: thank you. first option does not show the line anymore, although the tooltip pops up every second point. guess this is because of "null". second option crashes, because "labels" is an array of time values (e.g. "10:00", "10:01", "10:02", ...) not an array of numbers.

Comment: In the first fiddle I had to set `spanGaps: true` for it to show the lines. It seems to work with category (string) x-axis as well [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t36dfqeL/)